# Counting solutions to equations in $\mathbb{Q}(q)$

Tags: number-theory, extension-field

Consider $\mathbb{Q}(q)$, the field of rational functions in an indeterminate $q$. This field has unique $\mathbb{Q}$-ring involution $\psi$ sending $q$ to $q^{-1}$. Consider elements $a,b\in \mathbb{Q}(q)$ with $a\neq 0$. I am looking for solutions $x\in\mathbb{Q}(q)$ to the equation
$$x^2-\psi(x^2)+\psi(x)a+b=0.$$
My question is the following: How many solutions does this equation have? My hope is that this equation has a unique solution, in the sense that it looks like a quadratic equation with extra conditions. Does anyone know how to this problem?

Comment: What additional requirements do a,b satisfy? Notice that we have always -x as a solution as well when a=0.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I will make an edit, I want to assume that $a\neq 0$. Maybe if it makes it easier, also $b\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you have in general at most 2 solutions, given by intersecting a conic and a line.  But there are degenerate cases when you have infinitely many solutions.

**Notation**: Write $y=y_++\frac{q-q^{-1}}2y_-$ where $y_+=\frac12(y+\psi(y))$, $y_-=\frac{y-\psi(y)}{q-q^{-1}}$.  Note that we have similar decomposition algebraically as decomposing real and imaginary parts of a complex numbers, and $y_{\pm}\in\mathbb{Q}(q)^{\langle\psi\rangle}=\mathbb{Q}(q+q^{-1})=:k$.  Finally,
\begin{align*}
(yz)_+&=y_+z_++\frac{(q+q^{-1})^2-4}4y_-z_-\\
(yz)_-&=y_+z_-+y_-z_+
\end{align*}

So our equation:
$$x^2-\psi(x^2)+\psi(x)a+b=0$$
decomposes into a pair of equations
$$
\begin{aligned}
0&=[x^2-\psi(x^2)+\psi(x)a+b]_+\\
&=x_+a_+-\frac{(q+q^{-1})^2-4}4x_-a_-+b_+\\
0&=[x^2-\psi(x^2)_- + \psi(x)a+b]_-\\
&=2x_+x_- + x_+a_- + x_-a_++b_-
\end{aligned}
$$
The first equation is a line, and the second equation is a conic (or two lines $x_\pm=\frac12 a_{\mp}$ if $b_-=\frac12a_+a_-$) in $k^2$.  So there are at most 2 intersection points in the $(x_+,x_-)$-plane unless the conic is degenerate and the first line coincide with one of the lines.